# Message on empty table Angular

Tags: angularjs, html-table, message

I am filling in a table within Angular but I want it to be able to show an error message is my array is empty, I can find the solution when its with lists but I don't know how to convert this to a table.

Any help would be appreciated!

Code:

```
 <table class="datatable">
  <tr>
    <th><input ng-model="allSelected" ng-change="selectAll()" type="checkbox"></th>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>
      <div class="headerButtons"><a ng-click="order('name')">Name<i class="material-icons md-18">swap_vert</i></a></div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div class="headerButtons"><a ng-click="order('type')">Type<i class="material-icons md-18">swap_vert</i></a></div>
    </th>
      <th>
      <div class="headerButtons"><a ng-click="order('type')">Dimensions<i class="material-icons md-18">swap_vert</i></a></div>
    </th>
        <th>
      <div class="headerButtons"><a ng-click="order('type')">Media Linkage<i class="material-icons md-18">swap_vert</i></a></div>
    </th>

  </tr>

  <tr ng-repeat="file in (filteredImageData = (imageData | filter:search | filter:myFilter))">
    <context-menu ng-init="file.hidden = true" owner="file" menu-data="contextMenuFields"></context-menu>
    <td><input ng-model="file.selected" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><div ng-if="file.type == 'image'">
      <a ng-click="openCarousel(file,$index)"><img ng-src="http://XXXX/{{file.url}}"  width="65" height="65" get-image-resolution="file.size"></div>
      <div ng-if="file.type == 'video'">
      <a  ng-click="openCarousel(file,$index)"><i class ="material-icons md-24">videocam</i ></div>
      <div ng-if="file.type == 'audio'">
      <a ng-click="openCarousel(file,$index)"><i class="material-icons md-24">volume_up</i></div>
      </td>
      <td>
      {{file.name}}
      <div class="dropdown"><a ng-click="contextMenuFields.show($event,file)"><i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i></div></td>        

     <td>{{file.type}}<i class="greyedOut"> {{file.name | getextension}}</i></td>
     <td>{{file.size.x}}<i class="greyedOut"> x</i> {{file.size.y}}<i class="greyedOut"> px</i></td>
     <!--<td>blurp{{getRes(http://XXXX/{{file.url}})}}</td>-->
     <td>{{file.folder}}</td>

     <!--<td>{{file.type}}{{getExtension(file.name)}}</td>-->

  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the code to make use of `ng-if`. Below is the sample code you can use:

`<tr ng-if="(!filteredImageData || filteredImageData.length < 1)">
<td colspan="6">There are no records to show</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-if="filteredImageData" ng-repeat="file in (filteredImageData = (imageData | filter:search | filter:myFilter))">`

Comment: Cheers! Its still buggy when I am trying to do the following:

<div class="info"><a ng-class='{ sel: myFilter.type == "image" }' ng-click="myFilter.type = 'image'">Image ({{getTypeLength("image")}})</a></div>

Any idea why?

Comment: Try the code below:
`<div class="info"><a ng-class="{true:'sel'}[myFilter.type == 'image']" ng-click="myFilter.type = 'image'">Image ({{getTypeLength("image")}})</a></div> `
Hope this solves your issue... :)